# Filtering array with array_intersect() - values are equal as integers, but not as strings

Tags: php, arrays, casting, types, array-intersect

If I've got an array of values that are basically zero-padded string representations of various numbers and another array of integers, will `array_intersect()` still match elements of different types?

For example, would this work:

```
$arrayOne = array('0003', '0004', '0005');
$arrayTwo = array(4, 5, 6);

$intersect = array_intersect($arrayOne, $arrayTwo);

// $intersect would then be = "array(4, 5)"
```

And if not, what would be the most efficient way to accomplish this? Just loop through and compare, or loop through and convert everything to integers and run `array_intersect()` after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$ cat > test.php

```
<?php
$arrayOne = array('0003', '0004', '0005');
$arrayTwo = array(4, 5, 6);

$intersect = array_intersect($arrayOne, $arrayTwo);

print_r($intersect );

?>
```

$ php test.php

Array
(
)

$

So no, it will not.   But if you add

```
foreach($arrayOne as $key => $value)
{
   $arrayOne[$key] = intval($value);
}
```

you will get

$ php test.php

Array
(
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 5
)

Comment: Doesn't work when i test it.function matched_ids() {

    $cart_ids = array_merge(
        wp_list_pluck(WC()->cart->get_cart_contents(), 'variation_id'),
        wp_list_pluck(WC()->cart->get_cart_contents(), 'product_id')
    );

    $product_ids = get_option('restricted_product_ids');
    
    $ids         =  explode( ' ', $product_ids );
    
    foreach( $product_ids as $key => $value ) {
    
    $product_ids[$key] = intval($value);
    
    return array_intersect( $product_ids[$key], $cart_ids );
    
    }
    
}

Answer (score 4):

From https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php:

> ```
> Note:  Two elements are considered equal if and only if
> (string) $elem1 === (string) $elem2.
> In words: when the string representation is the same.
> ```

In your example, $intersect will be an empty array because 5 !== "005" and 4 !== "004"

Comment: And I think it should be mentioned that `(string)"5" === (string)5`.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that `array_intersect()` performs loose comparisons, but your zero-padded strings will not be evaluated as loosely equal when the integers are coerced to numeric strings.

This does not mean that you will need to abandon the native array intersect family of functions.  `array_uintersect()` is a very appropriate tool and, by casting the parameters as int type, will require no iterated function calls to suitably compare the values.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/CTbiq))

```
var_export(
    array_uintersect(
        $arrayOne,
        $arrayTwo,
        fn(int $a, int $b) => $a <=> $b
    )
);
// array (1 => '0004', 2 => '0005',)
```

Or swap the order of the input arrays: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/S3XTCG))

```
var_export(
    array_uintersect(
        $arrayTwo,
        $arrayOne,
        fn(int $a, int $b) => $a <=> $b
    )
);
// array (0 => 4, 1 => 5,)
```