# php array_intersect with strict type

Tags: php, casting, array-intersect

PHP [array_intersect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) does not have any option for strict type checking as they have given [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

```
$array1 = array(true,2);

$array2 = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);

var_dump(array_intersect($array1, $array2));
```

result is :

```
array(2) {
  [0] =>  bool(true)
  [1]  =>  int(2)
}
```

where expected result is

```
array(1) {
  [0]  =>  int(2)
}
```

Am I missing something ?

May be question is duplicated with [PHP array_intersect() - how does it handle different types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259457/php-array-intersect-how-does-it-handle-different-types)

Answer (score 3):

PHP isn't a strongly-typed language, as far as it is concerned anything that isn't false, is true, and will evaluate as such in boolean operations. 
You can get more info about this on the PHP Manual http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php

However, PHP does provide the functionality to strictly check types with `===`, as you said `array_intersect` doesn't use this functionality but it is possible to use `array_uintersect` to define your own callback function which will do the comparison of the values.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-uintersect.php

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna strict array_intersect, you can write your own method, like this:

```
<?php
    public function array_intersect_strict(array $array1, array $array2) {
        return array_filter($array1, function ($value) use ($array2) {
            return in_array($value, $array2, true);
        });
    }
```